# Does Redshift support the IEEE 754 floating point numbers?

Tags: database, floating-point, amazon-redshift, ieee-754, subnormal-numbers

Recently I encountered an overflow error when attempting to load data from a `DOUBLE PRECISION` column in a postgres database to a `DOUBLE PRECISION` column into AWS Redshift:

> Overflow, 2.8079240261080252e-316 (Double valid range 2.225074e-308 to 1.797693e+308)

Based on the [wikipedia entry for double precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) it seems like the range of numbers supported by redshift includes "normal doubles", but excludes "subnormal doubles".

As an additional check, I attempted to retrieve the smallest subnormal double, which was successful in postgres, but resulted in an overflow error in redshift:

```sql
SELECT '4.94065645841246544e-324'::DOUBLE PRECISION;
```

Based on this observed behavior, can we conclude that Redshift does not properly implement the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers? Does anyone have any relevant experience interoperating between systems that do and do not support subnormal numbers?

Comment: note that subnormals can have much reduced precision, hence you want to sway away from them if possible.  e.g. your ~2.8e-316 value only has ~9 significant decimal figures rather than the usual ~15.  could you just truncate these values towards zero?  values this small are often artifacts caused by numerical instability, or if you really do need values this small then you probably need to change scales, or do something else like log-transform them

Comment: A result of 2.80…•10^-316 is obviously not an overflow. I suspect underflow was signaled and Redshift is misreporting it. Underflow is signaled when a subnormal result occurs, with some variations depending on whether default exception handling is in effect and the result is exact. If this is the case, there is no reason to suspect Redshift has not properly implemented IEEE 754 except for the miscategorization of the exception.